# jQuery custom selector for text nodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, textnode

I would like to extract text from a DOM element using a jQuery custom selector. It should only select the text node without it's tagged siblings (much like /text() in XPath).

Background: I am working on a Firefox extension, that extracts some specific information (e.g. a username) on very different websites. Now I want my users to be able to dynamically add path definitions for new websites over a form as simple as possible:

> Add new Website:
>
> URL: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** (e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/")
>
> Path: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** (e.g. ".user-details>a:eq(0)" for the name of the user asking a question)

On stackoverflow for instance, $(path).text() will return the username as text. But on some other sites the username is available only as text node with tagged siblings, as in this example:

```
<div id="person">
    johndoe <span id="age">(57)</span>
    <span id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…</span>
</div>
```

Since jQuery doesn't provide a selector for text nodes (like /text() in XPath), I was hoping to find a solution creating a custom selector.

I know how to get the text node the 'non-selector' way:

```
var textNode = $('#person').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

alert(textNode); // gives me "johndoe"
```

How would I translate this into a custom selector? The following obviously doesn't work, since it always returns the complete element as soon as one part of it is a text node (as @VinayC explains in his answer):

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    getText: function(element){
        return $(element).contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;}).text();
    }
});

alert($('#person:getText')); //returns the whole DIV element
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJJbs/)

Maybe it's not possible to do this with jQuery custom selectors. That's why I'm thinking about going 'back' to XPath which seems more versatile.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're approaching this problem in the wrong direction. And if there's additional info we should be aware you should put it in your question (and not bury it in some comment)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on SO. What would be a better direction? Which info would you advise me to move into the question?

Comment: Both your comments on @VinayC answer provide additional information about the process you'd like to support and why you decided to do it with selector filters. Especially information from the first comment is very important and should be included (maybe into an even deeper detail) in the original question post.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: I edited my question trying to reflect your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is to create a jquery selector and the selector function is supposed to return boolean to indicate if the passed node has matched or not. So your current function returns a "true" for "#person" div ((actual return value is text within div which is non-empty and hence considered as true) and hence you get the div element as result.

You may try `getText: function(node){ return node.nodeType == 3;}` but this will work only jquery engine passes all document nodes including text nodes via selector functions (I am unaware if it does or does not). Alternate is to create an helper function instead of custom selector.

EDIT: how about extending jquery object? For example,

```
$.fn.extend({
    getText: function() {
        return this.contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;}).text();
    }
});

alert($('#person').getText());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `getText: function(node){ return node.nodeType == 3;}`doesn't seem to work. - Maybe the problem is, that a customer selector can only walk through non-text-nodes?(opposed to .contents())

Comment: The reason why I'm looking for a solution with selectors: I am working on a Firefox extension, that extracts some specific information on very different websites. Now I want my users to be able to dynamically add path definitions for new websites. Beeing able to use only selectors would make this much easier. I guess if this is not possible with sizzle, I will have to find a solution with XPath. Any thoughts?

Comment: @modoq, why not extend jquery with helper function - see the edited answer?

Comment: I want my users to be able to extend the functionality of my addon by providing 1.) an url to a new website and 2.) the path to the specific piece of information on that site. With your solution I would need to either give them access to the whole jQuery expression somehow (problem: security, misuse?) or provide some point-and-click way of concatenating different selectors and helper functions (complicated to implement and use, since I might need other helper functions).

Comment: Trying to solve this same problem, and did a bit more research first.  Yes, it seems that [jQuery traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) almost always skip text nodes without sending them to the selector.  One exception is `.content()`, which doesn't make things any more convenient...