# How to implement arbitrary textnode selection in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, textnode

I've realized that several times lately I've had a need to incorporate text node selection in some jQuery selectors.

jQuery doesn't natively really have any support for textnodes. Most answers about questions of this type recommend using [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) but this doesn't really come under "selectors" but rather "traversing". As such it only gives direct children and it gives all children, not just text nodes.

I find I need to select all the text nodes within arbitrarily marked-up text, so some of the text nodes I'll be interested in will be grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc:

```
<div id="formattedText">
  This is a <b>sample</b> block <a href="http://somewhere.com">of <em>text</em></a>
  that I might want to get a list of <span class="groovy">all</span> text nodes in.
</div>
```

So the most expressive way to achieve this rather than trying to implement recursive calls to `.children()` would be to extend the jQuery selector to something like this:

```
var txtNodes = $('#formattedText §');
```

Where `§` stands for some new bit of syntax I would add to jQuery representing a text node. I'd have to find some unused ASCII symbol or something like the `:odd()` extensions:

```
var txtNodes = $('#formattedText:textNodes()');
```

How would one go about extending jQuery's selector engine this way? I'd assume I'd want to hook into their existing DOM-walking methods and not have to resort to building new ones?

Or maybe there's an expressive trick using `.contents()` that I'haven't thought of that does do what I want without me having to extend jQuery?

---

<sup>My use case: I want to do custom "highlighting" of text from a 3rd party website in a userscript (greasemonkey etc). By "custom" I mean different patterns will get different `background-color`s etc. So I need all the text nodes no matter their depth and I don't want the tags around them and I don't want all the text in one big chunk as `.text()` would give me.</sup>

Comment: Related: [jQuery custom selector for text nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866763)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't caught up on the new signature required to make `:`-pseudo-selector extensions, but here's a method:

```
(function($){

    function walk( node, ret ) {
        var ret = ret || [],
            cur,
            nodes = node.childNodes;

        for( var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; ++i ) {
            cur = nodes[i];

            if( cur.nodeType === 1 ) {
                walk( cur, ret );
            }
            else if( cur.nodeType === 3 ) {
                ret.push( cur );
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    $.fn.findText = function() {

        var ret = this.map( function() {
            return walk( this );
        });

        return this.pushStack( ret, "textNodes", "" );
    };

})( jQuery );
```

On the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LAarE/1) here, I'll iterate over the found textnodes in order they were found so you can see the order on the page.

Comment: Nice. I was expecting it would need to be hairier than that (-: